# Запрос на обновление данных не работает

Tags: php, mysqli

У меня есть таблица, внутри которой циклом выводится некоторая информация и еще одним столбцом выводится элемент в виде ссылки `<?= "<a href='?red={$task['task_type']}&id={$task['id']}#zatemnenie'>Редактировать</a>" ?>` при нажатии на нее появляется форма в виде всплывающего окна.

Форма:

```
  <form action="/" method="get">

    <input type="hidden" name="redt" value="redTask">

    <p>
        <strong>
            <?= $taskType['name'] ?> - <?= $taskType['type'] ?>
        </strong>
        <br>
        <?php if ($taskType['obc'] == 1):?>
            <label for="">Выберите obc -- </label><select name="obc" id="">
                <option value="-1">Отсутствует</option>
                <option value="1">Да</option>
                <option value="0">Нет</option>
            </select><br>
        <?php endif;?>

        <?php if ($taskType['sr'] == 1):?>
            <label for="">Выберите sr -- </label><select name="sr" id="">
                <option value="-1">Отсутствует</option>
                <option value="1">Да</option>
                <option value="0">Нет</option>
            </select><br>
        <?php endif;?>

        <?php if ($taskType['osr'] == 1):?>
            <label for="">Выберите osr -- </label><select name="osr" id="">
                <option value="-1">Отсутствует</option>
                <option value="1">Да</option>
                <option value="0">Нет</option>
            </select><br>
        <?php endif;?>
    </p>
    <button type="submit">Сохранить</button>
</form>
```

Далее я прописываю запрос к БД на редактирование записи, айдишник которой я получил от ссылки:

```
   if ($_GET[redt]==='redTask'){
   $redtt=mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE 'tasks' SET `obc`='{$_GET['obc']}', `sr`='{$_GET['sr']}',`osr`='$_GET['osr']' WHERE 'id'={$_GET['id']}");
```

}

Проблема в том, что запрос в таком виде не обновляет строку в БД, но если я пропишу айдишник статичным числом, редактирование происходит. Так вот, как сделать, что бы редактирование происходило по взятому из ссылки параметра ?

Comment: А где в html вы передаёте `id`? В упор не вижу

Comment: @ArchDemon  `<?= "<a href='?red={$task['task_type']}&id={$task['id']}#zatemnenie'>Редактировать</a>" ?>` в ссылке

Comment: Ссылка - это хорошо, но а в форме он где передаётся?

Comment: @ArchDemon в форме передается только параметр при получении которого создается запрос на редактирование... вы тонко намекаете на то, что в форме не хватает передачи параметра id ?

Comment: @ArchDemon  разве параметр в запрос обязательно должен приходить из формы ?